# Xcode 6.1 - I can't modify the elements of a xib

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6

I have Xcode version 6.1 on Yosemite.

I downloaded an Xcode project from git and when I select a xib file (create with Xcode version 6.1) I see that all elements of xib file are disable:

[image]

I try to download again the project and I make a clean of the project but the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is because something called 'size classes'. This is very useful tool to set specific constraints based on device and orientation.

Every view controller gets 2 size clases: a horizontal and a vertical size class, and each one has 3 possible values: compact, regular or any. 
For example: 'wCompact hRegular' is for all iPhones in portrait and 'wAny hAny" is Base configuration (all layouts).

The project may have assigned those constraints to a particular combination of them.

You probably have something blue on the bottom of the view that says 'wCompact hCompact'(or 'wCompact hRegular'...). Click on the label and switch it to other combinations until constraints get enabled.